# How to configure a host file to map an IP address to any SSL secured domain name?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl-certificate, host

i have a SSl secured link and I need an IP to be mapped against it, I tried with general mapping in hosts file by using below snippet:

```
<IP Address>  uploads.mydomain.com
```

in above snippet **uploads.mydomain.com** is SSl certified and hence opens up with https protocol,

but after above configuration, when I hit to the mapped IP i do not get navigated to SSL certified page, rather I am navigated to Non SSL page of same domain.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to do a redirect in your web server, as far as I know, there's no way to specify protocols or ports in host files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host files only do address translation. Meaning they translate a certain name like uploads.mydomain.com to an ip address. It is not aware of any protocols. Hence what you are trying to achieve is not possible with hostfiles.

You will need to configure a redirect or rewrite on your webserver rather than on your client.